# Why is there no potential difference between my body and neither terminal of a battery?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields, voltage

Right now I'm holding a voltmeter. I measure the voltage between terminals of a AAA battery. It reads 1.47V. Next I measure the voltage between the positive terminal of the battery and my hand (I'm not touching the battery with any part of my body) - 0V. The same goes for my hand and the negative terminal. Now, voltage is the line integral of the electric field and line integrals are path independent in conservative fields, so I expect that $V_{positive-negative} = V_{positive-hand} + V_{hand-negative}$. Yet, 0 + 0 clearly doesn't yield 1.47. Why doesn't the path independence principle hold in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the electric field created by a battery non-conservative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377411/why-is-the-electric-field-created-by-a-battery-non-conservative)

Comment: Note that for any *physical* voltmeter, there must be a small current through (a typical hand-held voltmeter has in input impedance of roughly 10 mega-ohms) to read a voltage across.  Do you see a closed path for a current through when you connect one probe to the battery and the other probe to your hand?

Comment: @Armadillomon: The field generated by a battery isn't conservative to begin with; that's why it is known as "emf" and not "potential difference".

Comment: @user7777777, why do you say the *field* generated by a battery isn't conservative?  Are you referring to the electric field due to the battery?  Consider an isolated battery - is the electric field due to this battery non-conservative?  If so, according to $\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$, there should be an associated time dependent magnetic field shouldn't there?

Comment: @user7777777, I asked the question *after* I checked the link.

Comment: Also, here is another answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/387494/the-significance-of-electromotive-force-being-non-conservative-in-origin

Comment: @user7777777, you're avoiding my question.  When you write "the field generated by a battery isn't conservative", do you mean the electric field and if so, where is the associated timed dependent magnetic field?

Comment: @Alfred Centauri: Yes, I am referring to the electric field. Your reference to Maxwell's equations again shows that you have *not* read the post that I linked (and its comments). Literally, it says "Why is the electric field created by a battery non-conservative?". Let me quote: `*aren't [Maxwell's equations] universally valid, compatible with both special relativity and quantum mechanics?* No, they're not. Maxwell's equations are classical. For example, you're not going to be able to explain the photoelectric effect using Maxwell's equations.` straight from the comments.

Comment: @user7777777, does this quote answer my question?

Comment: @user7777777, I'm reading the post again and Ben Crowell's *answer* clearly doesn't imply the electric *field* of the battery is non-conservative:  *"So the short answer is that the F inside the battery contains a term from an effective chemical force, and this force is not the same as the electrical force. In fact, it's in the opposite direction."*  - You can also see this at the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force#Formal_definitions) which shows that emf has terms from effective chemical and thermal *forces*.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri: You are correct about the force being non-conservative; that's why it is called "emf". However, the charges are still affected by this non-conservative force, and by definition, $\mathbf{F} = q \mathbf{E}$, so this force is still part of the electric field. The net electric field is not conservative as it is the sum of a conservative component and the emf, $IR = V + \mathcal{E}$. By your argument, if the field were conservative, charge will not be able to flow along a closed circuit at all.

Comment: @user7777777, I haven't made an argument.  I've simply asked you where the time dependent magnetic field is that is associated with a non-conservative electric field.  If a battery in isolation (no current through) produces a non-conservative electric field, then $\nabla\times\mathbf{E}_{BAT} \ne 0$ and thus $-\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \ne 0$.  As far as I can tell, your claim is that this isn't true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85501/discussion-between-alfred-centauri-and-user7777777).

Answer (score 3):

If you attach a voltmeter between two otherwise isolated things (e.g. a battery and something else such as an isolated metal sphere) then current will begin to flow through the voltmeter from the one initially at higher to the one at lower potential. If the capacitance of the objects is not too large, then it won't take long for this current to change the potential of one or both till they are at equal potential. This accounts for your observations. In this case it is the battery which does not have much capacitance; your body has larger capacitance, and planet Earth a very much larger one. However, you were probably reasonably well isolated from the Earth for your experiment, so you could ignore the latter. The main point is that the battery can quickly be brought to one potential or another when it is contacted with other things; we say it is "floating".

Comment: So is there any way to actually measure this initial potential difference between two isolated objects?