# Does Kirchhoff's Law always hold?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, approximations

There's a bit of furore from this question on Youtube involving Dr. Walter Lewin and another Youtuber. With Dr. Lewin claiming Kirchhoff's Law doesn't always hold when magnetic fields are involved, and that two voltmeters attached to identical places in a circuit can give different readings. Is this the case?

Original Video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TTEFF0D8SA

Dr. Lewin's response :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQqYs6O2MPw

Comment: Possibly related:https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136431/25301

Comment: It depends on what we call "Kirchhoff's law". What do *you* call Kirchhoff's law?

Comment: Related: [Kirchhoff's Voltage Law in a General Electromagnetic Field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442183/22927), [KVL for non- conservative E-field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443242/22927).

Comment: I would say a complete statement of KVL should start with the phrase "In a lumped circuit...". In which case KVL applies in a universe that contains a non-lumped circuit. It just doesn't tell you anything useful about the non-lumped circuits. Part of the definition of a lumped circuit is that there isn't any significant changing magnetic flux in the loops formed by the wires interconnecting the circuit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...claiming Kirchhoff's Law doesn't always hold when magnetic fields are involved, and that two voltmeters attached to identical places in a circuit can give different readings. Is this the case?

It is true that two voltmeters connected to same pair of points in a circuit can show different values. The reason is the voltmeters can be affected differently by a solenoidal electric field which is present since there is changing magnetic flux.

What is the point of contention here between prof. Lewin and his oponents is terminology(semantics) of the words like potential and voltage.

As others on this site have observed, whether KVL holds depends on:

- which version of KVL we use: there is the historical version about sum of electromotive forces in a circuit, and there is the modern textbook form about potential drops along a circuit;
- what we mean by voltage (or electromotive force, if we use the original version of KVL).

Prof. Lewin seems to understand voltage as either 1) integral of total electric  field along some path connecting two points 2) whatever voltmeter connected to two points shows. In both cases, his voltage is ambiguous, as it depends either on the chosen paths in space, or on how the probes of the voltmeter are arranged in space. With voltages defined as integrals of total electric field, the modern KVL indeed does not hold, because their sum equals minus net electromotive force for the circuit and this emf is arbitrary, depending on how we arrange the integration paths (or wires).

But the textbook authors writing KVL applies to such situations with changing magnetic flux are not wrong, because their concept of voltage between two points is that it is difference of electric potentials of those points, irrespective of whether a voltmeter or other device can measure it. This is a prevailing convention because:

- electric potential can always be naturally and uniquely defined as the potential of the conservative part of the electric field, i.e. the Coulomb-integral potential of all charges around, even in high frequency AC circuits with solenoidal fields everywhere (such potential is less useful in such high frequency cases but there is no problem in its definition)
- this definition is very useful in lumped elements model of circuit, because then each pair of terminals in a circuit has unique potential drop, equal to difference of Coulomb potentials on those terminals.

With prof. Lewin's implied definition (integral of total electric field), we would encounter various problems. For example, line integral of electric field taken along path connecting two terminals of an ideal solenoid in which electric current is changing would be arbitrary, dependent on the chosen integration path. It could always be made zero if the path is chosen entirely inside the perfect conductor of the solenoid. Thus the inductor would have no single voltage and we could not use the usual tools of analysis for lumped element model.

Of course, the standard theory asserts that potential drop across ideal inductor is unique:
$$
p.d.(ideal~inductor) = L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$
This potential drop cannot be understood as integral of total electric field (which would depend on the choice of path), but it is integral of electrostatic part of it (which does not depend on that choice), or equivalently, minus electromotive force inside the solenoid - the "solenoidal component of electric field" or the "induced field" integrated along the path that is entirely in the wire of the solenoid.

Comment: Beautiful answer. In current varying circuits however the coulomb potential will vary with time as well.

Comment: $$\phi_{B} = L I$$ $$ \frac{d\phi_{B}}{dt} = L \frac{dI}{dt}$$ next applying faradays law, $\int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} =  -\frac{d\phi_{B}}{dt}$  We then get $$\int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} = -L \frac{dI}{dt}$$  I am struggling to understand what you mean by "This voltage drop cannot be understood as integral of total electric field (which would depend on the choice of path), but it is integral of electrostatic part of it", the inductors emf,is purely due to  a solenoidal electric field, and thus the electrostatic part of it is 0?

Comment: How is this definition of EMF incompatable with the uniqueness of the inductors voltage drop? Aslong as you follow the inductors wire the emf is unique for a given start and end point. Ofcourse you aren't going to follow any other path than the wire, as by substituting faradays law into the equation, you are finding the emf about the boundary of  surface with a flux $\phi_{B}$ with current I, which is following the wire and no other path. Applying this equation for a loop not following the wire, is invalid given its derivation.

Comment: @jensenpaull Induced EMF on inductor indeed is due to induced field, which is a solenoidal field. But potential drop on that inductor is not the same thing. In a perfect inductor, net electric field in the conductor vanishes, so the conservative part of the field cancels out the induced part of the field, so potential drop equals minus the induced emf. In real inductors with resistance and capacitance, total electric field does not vanish in the coil conductor, so the conservative field does not completely cancel out the induced field, so potential drop is not simply related to induced EMF.

Comment: @jensenpaull the loop integral you mention is not "voltage drop", but it is the total induced EMF in the loop. Potential drop is a different thing.

Comment: I've changed the unfortunate term "voltage drop" into "potential drop", which is clearer and correct.