# Is there no net voltage over an ideal inductor/coil? No voltage drop?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, inductance

If you have a coil with self inductance:
$$ \varepsilon= - L \frac{dI}{dt} $$

Then the current is lagging behind the voltage.

If you attach a AC source on the coil/inductor and have an AC power source, then at the highest current there is no internal resisting voltage produced bij the self inductor.

$$ V_{\text{produced by battery}} - \varepsilon =0 (?)$$

My question. Is there no net voltage over the inductor at any moment? I.e. the inductor will always perfectly cancel the voltage produced by the AC source? How do you calculate this?

Comment: I am confused by your diagram. Are you imagining ideal elements, so that neither the battery nor the inductor has any internal resistance? In that case the steady state would be infinite current in the loop you have drawn. You mention an AC power source. Is that also in parallel with your ideal DC battery and ideal inductor? Is your AC power source an ideal voltage source, or an ideal current source?

Comment: @rob I think he means an AC source (mistakenly referred to as a battery), connected with an inductor.

Comment: Yes I mean AC source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Kirchoffs law does not hold. This is because there are changing magnetic  fields.

Imagine I have a battery and an inductor, such that the inductance L is the inductance of the entire circuit.

**Using faradays law:**

$$\int \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} = -\frac{d \phi_{B}}{dt}$$

$$-V_{batt} + \epsilon_{wire} = -\frac{d \phi_{B}}{dt}$$

$$-V_{batt} + \epsilon_{wire} = - L \frac{dI}{dt}$$

$$ \epsilon_{wire} = V_{batt} - L \frac{dI}{dt}$$

Now, in general, $\epsilon_{wire}$ does not need to be zero.

Using the steady state approximation:

$$\epsilon_{wire} = IR$$

Our equation reduces to:

$$ IR = V_{batt} - L \frac{dI}{dt}$$

When $R=0, \epsilon_{wire} = 0$, and thus the potential across the  inductor is zero.

You find that in order for this to be true.

$$V_{batt} = L \frac{dI}{dt}$$

Aka the contribution to the pd of the battery, cancels out the induced emf.

I would like to point out, that the validity of using ohms law here is not particularly rigourous

Comment: So this means that in an ideal situation without resistance my premise is true? That the voltage produced by the AC source is exactly getting cancelled inside the inductor?

Comment: @bananenheld Of course (using Kirchhoff's law, this would be just a corollary).

Comment: Potential difference on an inductor is not given by $RI$. This implied variant of Ohm's law does not apply to inductors (or any other conductor that experience electromotive force other than potential drop).

Answer (score 1):

In AC circuits "voltage on inductor" means difference of electric potential between the inductor's two terminals. In your example where ideal voltage source is driving the circuit with ideal inductor, drop of potential on inductor is determined by the voltage source. For the simplest AC source,  it is sinusoidal function of time:

$$
V_0\sin \omega t,
$$
where $V_0$ is amplitude and $\omega$ frequency of the source.

There is no cancellation of voltage. Cancellation can happen in the sense that in ideal inductor, induced EMF is cancelled by the potential drop. Why? In any inductor free of external forces, the induced EMF is
$$
-L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$
Provided the inductor is ideal (made of zero resistance conductor, zero capacitance), potential drop is
$$
L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$

These two forces act in opposite directions (hence the opposite sign) and have the same magnitude, so they cancel each other in the sense that there is no remaining electric field inside the conductor making up the ideal inductor.

In real inductor, this is no longer true, because there is some residual electric field inside the conductor and voltage isn't given by $LdI/dt$.

Voltage on inductor is only due to electrostatic component of electric field. On ideal inductor, this is zero only in special time instants when $dI/dt =0$.

Comment: I'm talking about specifically in the ideal sense. Your comment confuses me because it says there is no cancellation of voltage but then afterwards you suggest that it is so.

Comment: There is no cancellation of voltage on any single component. There is cancellation in the sense that sum of all potential drops an all components in closed circuit is zero.

Comment: I think I am completely missing the point. Imagine if the voltage created by the AC source at any instant is $V$. Then at that moment of time the changing current through the ideal inductor will produce a induced EMF exactly opposite. $\varepsilon = - V$?

Comment: @bananenheld Yes, in ideal inductor the induced EMF is such that it is equal in magnitude and opposite in its effect on mobile charges when compared to potential drop imposed by the AC voltage source.

Comment: Thanks @Ján Lalinský

Answer (score 0):

There is a net voltage over the inductor most of the time.

Let's say that the AC source has a sinusoidal voltage:
$$U=U_0\sin\omega t$$
Using Kirchhoff's law, the sum of the voltages is equal to zero:
$$U_0\sin\omega t-L\frac{dI}{dt}=0$$
$$U_0\sin\omega t=L\frac{dI}{dt}$$
Separating the variables,
$$U_0\sin\omega t\, dt=L\, dI$$
And integrating,
$$\int U_0\sin\omega t\, dt=\int L\, dI$$
$$I+C=-\frac{U_0}{\omega L}\cos\omega t$$
Because of symmetry, the current amount needs to be symmetric over the $t$ axis, and $C=0$:
$$I=-\frac{U_0}{\omega L}\cos\omega t=-\frac{1}{\omega L}U_0\sin\left(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
Therefore, the current really lags behind the voltage, and voltage across the inductor is nonzero, except at the moments of time when $\omega t=(2N+1)\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: Kirchoffs law does not technically hold here, as there are changing magnetic fields.

Comment: @jensenpaull A lumped model is assumed, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/446454/does-kirchhoffs-law-always-hold).

Comment: Regardless, I have many doubts about that accepted answer. Which I might add, also points out its flaws.  KLR is derived by $\nabla × \vec{E} = 0$,  which is not the case here,  just because you have lumped elements doesn't mean you shouldn't use the correct equations

Comment: Isn't the whole premise then right because of: $U - U_L=0$? The induced emf inside the inductor always perfectly cancels the emf produced by the battery. Translating this into math gives: $U_0 \sin{\omega t} - L \frac{dI}{dt}=0$

Comment: Your "V' is not the voltage across the inductor, the voltage across the inductor is zero for this diagram.

Comment: By definition, your equation always gives an emf of zero across the inductor. Because you have set it to 0, and then solved for I that makes it always zero.

Comment: KVL is certainly valid and used all the time in analyzing circuits like this with lumped inductors. Voltage in this context is not the integral of the E-field (which would be zero in an ideal inductor). The inductor voltage is $L\ dI/dt$. This answer is correct.

Comment: @jensenpaull My equation is a direct consequence of the Kirchhoff's law: the sum of potential drops is equal to zero. Why wouldn't that make sense?

Comment: Puk, although I agree the induced voltage is Ldi/dt, OP asks the net voltage in the inductor. Would zero not be the correct answer?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are 2 definitions of kirchoffs loop rule. The one that I think makes more physical sense, and the less hand wavy one with lumped elements. Comes from the fact that $\oint \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} = 0$, which is inturn saying "the sum of potential drops is zero", but when there are changing magnetic fields, this doesn't equal zero. Unless modifying KLR to mean something different. I am not specifically familiar with this modified one.

Comment: @jensenpaull The voltage drops in the battery and the voltage are the same, because KVL holds. Again, voltage in this context is not the integral of the E-field, which is path dependent and would be zero if you integrate along the inductor coil. Engineers analyze such circuits using Kirchhoff's laws all the time, to great success. Claiming Kirchhoff's laws don't hold requires sticking to a narrow definition of voltage that's not useful in this context.

Comment: Will have to do further reading on voltage in this context. However i think the e.dl definition is the one that OP means.